# get json and see if there is not found

Tags: php, json, unirest

i want the php script to be able the get json using Unirest php

```
<?php
  require_once 'src/Unirest.php';
    $word  = 'Cartoon newttork';
    // return: convert-spaces-to-underscore-and-lowercase-with-php
    $word = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($word));

    // These code snippets use an open-source library.
    $response = Unirest\Request::get("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/$word",
      array(
      "Accept" => "application/json", // accept app as json
      "app_id" => "xxxxx", // app id found in dashboard
      "app_key" => "xxxxxx" //app key also found in dashboard
      )
    );
      $word_name = $response->body;
    if ($word_name === "Not Found") {
      echo "Not Found";
  }

  ?>
```

i want is to be something like this

```
  $word_name = $response->body;
    if ($word_name === "Not Found") {
      echo "Not Found";
  }
```

P.S if you have another php http client that is better write it down also

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Maybe better check the status code, e.g. `if (404 === $response->code)...`

Comment: Thank you! It work